# Visualize the class structure in a .NET dll

Tags: c#, .net

I get a library with two DLLs, but without the detailed document. I want get a quick view of its class design.

I know that I can use the Object Browser in Visual Studio to look into them. But it is not very intuitive. Is there a tool that displays the dependency graph of the library, or more formally the UML diagram. The input is just the DLL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of Visual Studio you have, you can use the [class designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek97fxxe.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're after the class diagram? Other UML diagrams are very hard to reverse engineer.

You could have a try [with several extensions for Visual Studio](http://www.olegsych.com/2010/01/uml-modeling-and-code-generation-in-visual-studio-2010/)